# What is the possible range of $1-2ax$ in this inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have the inequality $-18 > 6-12ax$ and are asked to find the possible  range of $1-2ax$.

I reasoned that $1-12ax = 6-12ax-5$ therefore I substituted and subtracted $-5$ from the other side of the inequality to get my answer:

$$-23>1-2ax$$

However the answer was $-3>1-2ax$.

They reasoned that $1-2ax = (6-12ax)/6$ and divided the other side of the inequality by six as well getting the correct answer stated above.

My question is, why was it wrong to subtract both sides by $5$?

Comment: There is a mistake you are making : you have $-18 > 6 - 12 ax$. After subtracting $5$ from both sides, you get $-23 > 1 - \color{red}{12}ax$. However, you have written $\color{blue}{2}ax$ instead of $12$, so you have made a mistake. the statement $-23 > 1 - 12ax$ is correct : there is nothing wrong in subtracting $5$ from both sides. Similarly in dividing by $6$.

Comment: $6(1-2x)=6-12x$

Answer (score 2):

$-18 > 6-12ax \iff -18 > 6(1-2ax) \iff -3> 1-2ax$.